# 400 bad request when attempting connection to AWS Neptune with IAM enabled

Tags: amazon-neptune

I am unable to connect to neptune instance that has IAM enabled. I have followed the AWS documentation (corrected a few of my silly errors on the way) but without luck.

When I connect via my Java application using the SigV4Signer and when I use the gremlin console, I get a 400 bad request websocket error.

```
o.a.t.g.d.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler : Could not process the response

io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 400 Bad Request
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker13.verify(WebSocketClientHandshaker13.java:267)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker.finishHandshake(WebSocketClientHandshaker.java:302)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketClientHandler.channelRead0(WebSocketClientHandler.java:69)
```

When I run `com.amazon.neptune.gremlin.driver.example.NeptuneGremlinSigV4Example` (from my machine over port-forwarding AND from the EC2 jumphost) I get:

`java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for an available host - check the client configuration and connectivity to the server if this message persists`

I am able to connect to my neptune instance using the older deprecated certificate mechanism.  I am using a jumphost ec2 instance and port-forwarding.

I believe that the SigV4 aspect is working as in the neptune audit logs I can see attempts to connect with the aws_access_key:

`1584098990319, <jumphost_ip>:47390, <db_instance_ip>:8182, HTTP_GET, [unknown], [unknown], "HttpObjectAggregator$AggregatedFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: CompositeByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0, components=0)) GET /gremlin HTTP/1.1 upgrade: websocket connection: upgrade sec-websocket-key: g44zxck9hTI9cZrq05V19Q== sec-websocket-origin: http://localhost:8182 sec-websocket-version: 13 Host: localhost:8182 X-Amz-Date: 20200313T112950Z Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<my_access_key>/20200313/eu-west-2/neptune-db/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;sec-websocket-key;sec-websocket-origin;sec-websocket-version;upgrade;x-amz-date, Signature=<the_signature> content-length: 0", /gremlin`

But when I look

This is the policy that I created:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "neptune-db:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:neptune-db:eu-west-2:<my_aws_account>:*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have previously tried with a policy that references my cluster resource id.
I created a new api user with this policy attached as its only permission.  (I've tried this twice).

IAM is showing my that the graph-user I created has not successfully logged in (duh).

Seems that the issue is with the IAM set-up somewhere along the line.  Is it possible to get more information out of AWS with regards to why the connection attempt is failing?

I am using the most recent release of Neptune and the 3.4.3 Gremlin Driver and console.  I am using Java 8 when running the `NeptuneGremlinSigV4Example` and building the libraries to deploy to the console.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from the audit log output that the SigV4 Signature that is being created is using `localhost` as the `Host` header.  This is most likely due to the fact that you're using a proxy to connect to Neptune.  By default, the `NeptuneGremlinSigV4Example` assumes that you're connecting directly to a Neptune endpoint and reuses the endpoint as the `Host` header in creating the Signature.

To get around this, you can use the following example code that overrides this process and allows you to use a proxy and still sign the request properly.

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-neptune-samples/tree/master/gremlin/gremlin-java-client-demo

I was able to get this to work using the following.

- Create an SSL tunnel from you local workstation to your EC2 jumphost:

```
ssh -i <key-pem-file> -L 8182:<neptune-endpoint>:8182 ec2-user@<ec2-jumphost-hostname>
```

- Set the following environment variables:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<access_key>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret_key>
export SERVICE_REGION=<region_id>  (i.e. us-west-2)
```

- Once the tunnel is up and your environment variables are set, use the following format with the `Gremlin-Java-Client-Demo`:

```
java -jar target/gremlin-java-client-demo.jar --nlb-endpoint localhost --lb-port 8182 --neptune-endpoint <neptune-endpoint> --port 8182 --enable-ssl --enable-iam-auth
```

Comment: thanks Taylor  I will look at that sample code.  I did wonder whether it was the localhost aspect, so i ran the `NeptuneGremlinSigV4Example` from my ec2 jumphost also with the same `TimeoutException` mentioned above.

Comment: The `TimeoutException` may suggest another issue.  Are you using SSH proxy and tunneling through your jumphost, or are you actually setting up a NAT and doing port forwarding.  I don't recall if the latter would require also allowing your source IP address via the Security Group on Neptune.  That might be something for you to try.  That `TimeoutException` coming from the client typically suggest a lack of network connectivity.

Comment: When attempting locally, its an SSH proxy tunnel via jumphost.  But I get the same issue when running from the jumphost inside  the VPC with a direct connection.  Does the NeptuneClusterBuilder require use of either NLB or ALB, or can I use it with just the iamEnabled

Comment: I updated my instructions above to be a bit more detailed.  In addition, I've also validated that you should be able to run this on the jump host as well.  Just set the same environment variables listed above and then use the Java example as: `java -jar target/gremlin-java-client-demo.jar --neptune-endpoint <neptune-endpoint> --port 8182 --enable-ssl --enable-iam-auth`

Comment: thanks Taylor, I followed your instructions above, really appreciate you taking the trouble to post them.  Using the client-demo app the connection from my local machine to the iam enable neptune worked as described; I could see the dump of the vertexes on the graph.  I will able able to use those classes in my java project to facilitate running my application locally and within my VPC.

Comment: I do use the gremlin console a lot for my day-to-day interaction with Neptune.  Is there a monky-patch that I can use to spin up the gremlin console using the NeptuneClusterBuilder?  Otherwise presumably it's a question of locating where in the gremlin console code it makes a connection using the vanilla ClusterBuilder and reworking that.

Comment: You would have to rewrite the org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.SigV4WebSocketChannelizer to support signing using a different hostname from the host that you would use to connect.  If you're purely using the Gremlin Console for development efforts, I would look at something like ClientVPN (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html) or some other means for providing network-level secure access versus attempting to go through a proxy (bastion host or ELB).

Comment: In a pinch I have installed the gremlin console on the bastion. Not ideal. I'll take a look at those suggestions, thanks.

Comment: For anyone reading this thread in the future - there is a missing peice of information in the amazon documentation on how to connect the console to an iam enabled graph.  The enableSsl connectionPool property should be added and set to true in the connection configuration file.  I have notified amazon about this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-gremlin-console.html

Comment: I know this is an old thread but @TaylorRiggan, anyway I can use NeptuneClusterBuilder via Gradle, I do not see any library out there. I have a similar situation, where for local debugging i need to switch to localhost, using this NLB route makes sense for me.